# Ropsten infura test network + web3 js event listener

Tags: web3js, ropsten, infura

I have deployed contracts on ropsten test network.
truffle.js

```
ropsten: {
  provider: function() {  
    return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/<api-token>")
  },
  network_id: '*',
  gas:"4000000"
}
```

store.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint myVariable;
  event emitval();

  function setValue(uint x) public {
    emitval();
    myVariable = x;
  }

  function getValue() public returns (uint) {
    emitval();
    return myVariable;
  }
}
```

In my node js code I am using web3 js to call/listen methods/events from contracts.

my node js file is

```
web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/<api-token>'));
```

and for listening events I wrote

```
var contracts = new web3.eth.Contract(importedjson.abi, deployedaddressat)

contracts.events.emitval(function(error, result){
    if(error) { console.log(error);} 
    else { console.log('Event setVal:', result);}
})
```

When I am calling methods of solidity (setValue() or getValue() which emits emitval() event), I am not able to listen it on node js code.

Could you please help me out.
I am uisng latest web3js version "1.0.0-beta.33".

Answer (score 0):

I can't see such `setVal` events in your contract. Indeed, in the contract, the name is `emitval`. You can try to change your code

```
contracts.events.emitval(function(error, result){
    if(error) { console.log(error);} 
    else { console.log('Event setVal:', result);}
});
```

and alternative is to listen to all the contract events using `myContract.events.allEvents`. [ref](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id38)

Comment: Sorry my bad while posting query I have renamed event in solidity file but forget to rename it in node js code.. I have checked event name is same in solidity and node js code now but still unable to listen event.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Unable to listen for the custom event. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'));

With

web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/'));

It might be a websocket issue as web3 1.0 doesn't support events for http.